# NVIDIA Version Outdated Error when mine is updated

Tags: python, ffmpeg, gpu, nvidia

I'm trying to encode stuff with my NVIDIA GeForce MX150 (Driver Version: 461.09).

`import os`
`os.system(f'ffmpeg -i "Cells at Work Season 2 - Episode 07 - English Subbed.mp4" -c:a copy -c:v hevc_nvenc "07.mp4"')`

Whenever I'm trying to run it, I'm getting this error.

`[hevc_nvenc @ 0000017a8bdf7e40] Cannot load nvEncodeAPI64.dll`
`[hevc_nvenc @ 0000017a8bdf7e40] The minimum required Nvidia driver for nvenc is 436.15 or newer`
`Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height`
`Conversion failed!`

What bugs me is that it says that I need 436.15 or newer, and mine is 461.09. That means it should work, right? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Nvidia's GPU support matrix](https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-and-decode-gpu-support-matrix-new), the MX150 doesn't support NVENC, so it's probably a bad error message. Given that it lacks appropriate hardware, there's unlikely going to be a way to get it working.

Here's an excerpt of the table:

| BOARD | FAMILY | CHIP | NVENC Generation | Desktop/ Mobile | # OF CHIPS | # OF NVENC /CHIP | Total # of NVENC | Max # of concurrent sessions | H.264 (AVCHD) YUV 4:2:0 | H.264 (AVCHD) YUV 4:4:4 | H.264 (AVCHD) Lossless | H.265 (HEVC) 4K YUV 4:2:0 | H.265 (HEVC) 4K YUV 4:4:4 | H.265 (HEVC) 4K Lossless | H.265 (HEVC) 8k | HEVC 10-bit support | HEVC B Frame support |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GeForce MX150 > MX330 | Pascal | GP108 | N/A | M | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NO | NO | NO | NO | NO | NO | NO | NO | NO |